# How to disable logging arguments for ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I want to use Rails 6.1.0 feature `self.log_arguments = false` for `ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob` background job - responsible for sending emails with `.deliver_later`.

How to do it?

My goal is to remove or mask email addresses from logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just override the delivery job of your mailer like this:

```
class ExampleMailer < ApplicationMailer
  class NoArgumentsLoggingMailDeliveryJob < ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob
    self.log_arguments = false
  end
  self.delivery_job = NoArgumentsLoggingMailDeliveryJob
end
```

EDIT: This isn't enough to prevent logging of arguments when the mailer raises an exception so keep this in mind if you never want to log the arguments. This is the case at least with Sidekiq.